# Magento2 custom admin menu link is redirecting back to admin dashboard

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

I have created a menu in admin page and its showing properly and its having a link http://localhost/magento2/admin/asw_advanced/sales/index/key/17910c3f00de5194db7f0a418e9f9d38a487af1c29bdfb16fc1dd406eac24101/

when i clicked on this its redirecting to admin dashboard itself.
The error showin on the magento system log is..

```
[2016-04-04 06:57:59] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'header' tries to reorder itself towards 'global.notices', but their parents are different: 'page.wrapper' and 'notices.wrapper' respectively. [] []
[2016-04-04 06:57:59] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'page.breadcrumbs' tries to reorder itself towards 'notifications', but their parents are different: 'page.wrapper' and 'notices.wrapper' respectively. [] []
[2016-04-04 06:57:59] main.CRITICAL: Broken reference: the 'global.search' tries to reorder itself towards 'notification.messages', but their parents are different: 'header.inner.right' and 'header' respectively. [] []
```

when i disable the security key to url in store > advanced > admin the page works fine. How to make it work with security key enabled.?

Asw/Sample/etc/adminhtml/menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../Magento/Backend/etc/menu.xsd">
    <menu>
        <add id="Asw_Sample::advanced" title="Advanced Reports" module="Asw_Sample" sortOrder="30" resource="Asw_Sample::advanced"/>
        <add id="Asw_Sample::advanced_sales" title="Sales order" module="Asw_Sample" parent="Asw_Sample::advanced" sortOrder="1" action="asw_advanved/sales" resource="Asw_Sample::advanced_sales"/>
    </menu>
</config>
```

Asw/Sample/etc/acl.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Acl/etc/acl.xsd">
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <resource id="Asw_Sample::admin">
                <resource id="Asw_Sample::advanced" title="Advanced Reports" sortOrder="10" >
                    <resource id="Asw_Sample::advanced_sales" title="Sales Order" sortOrder="40"/>
                </resource>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</config>
```

Asw/Sample/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="Asw_Sample_advanced" frontName="asw_advanved">
            <module name="Asw_Sample" before="Magento_Backend"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Asw/Sample/Controller/Sales/Index.php

```
<?php
namespace Asw\Sample\Controller\Adminhtml\Sales;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{ 
    /**
     * @var PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param Context $context
     * @param PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }


    /**
     * say admin text
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        print("ssss");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. For me the solution was to have the route id and frontName have the same value. In your case this would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="asw_advanved" frontName="asw_advanved">
            <module name="Asw_Sample" before="Magento_Backend"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Comment: +1 This fixed my issue.  I can't believe that this bug exists, as its technically should be allowed to be different.

Answer (score 0):

Every things seems fine, I have the same problem. If you are using ubuntu then give read and execute permission to the file.

Comment: i have given full permission to all files, still the same issue